# Only if VisualStudio made folder is used, log file remains empty. Low level io used

Tags: c++, visual-studio

This is the situation ... Simple util class for assuring the log file presence. A constructor does `_sopen_s` and stores the file descriptor obtained. Here is the relevant line:

```
 ...
// inside a constructor receiving a file_name
errno_t rez = _sopen_s(&file_descriptor, file_name, O_WRONLY | O_APPEND | O_CREAT, _SH_DENYNO, _S_IREAD | _S_IWRITE);
// using `fstat()` for  checks here
// all is fine, exit the constructor
...
```

Obviously this is WINLAND and `_sopen_s()` is what is required. And admittedly, that "never" fails. Now there is this single method, in the same class:

```
   FILE* file_ptr(const char* options_ = "w") const noexcept
    {
        _ASSERTE(file_descriptor_ > -1);
        static FILE* file_ = _fdopen(file_descriptor_, options_);
        _ASSERTE(file_ != nullptr);
        _ASSERTE(0 == ferror( file_));
        return file_;
    }
```

That also, I have never seen fail. Calers uses that file pointer wherever else, as the first argument to `fprintf`. For log file writing and such. All of which blissfully and peacefully "just works".

Until. You are using as the log file name the application base name with ".log" suffix added.

Example: `".\myprog.exe.log"` . You hit F5, VS churns out all the output required for debugging in the 'Debug' folder and you focus on whatever you need to debug.

But that log file, `~\Debug\myprog.exe.log` remains empty after `myprog.exe` has finished. No exceptions and no errors being caught...

And ... if you decide your log file should be e.g. "d:/whatever.log", it remains nicely packed with the `fprintf()` output using the mechanism, as described above.

I assume there are some "special" permissions required to write into that file located inside those visual studio made build folders.

But no error is made and the whole mechanism works if file pointer is for the file located anywhere outside of those folders ...

Why is `fprintf` quietly not producing any output into these local log files, located in visual studio generated folders? Any idea anyone?

ps: yes all four x86 debug/release and x64 debug/release folders I have checked.
if the log files are in there, they are created and no errors are reported but they remain empty.

The machine is WIN10 PRO fully updated. Visual Studio 2019 and CL are also fully updated. SDK is the latest.

Comment: SO is filled with what-the-heck questions from programmers that look at the wrong file.  It isn't clear how the .log file in the Debug directory ever got created, but that's forever the danger of implicitly relying on the current working directory being set where you hope it is.  The default is to set it to the project directory and configurable with Project > Properties > Debugging > "Working Directory" setting.  It is pretty likely that you will have a permission problem after you deploy your program, the Program Files directory is protected.  So always favor a full path.

Comment: @HansPassant, you have deduced quia te a lot from my question, perhaps? As I said: the same symptoms are for all four locations where VS places four builds by default.  The log files (if we wish them in there) are always created in there. Created but left empty. This is just a development situation. For deployment we do not rely on users abilities; in deployment, we always place log files under %programdata%\ ... inside consistently decided locations.

Comment: Sure, we do take the cues provided by the question.  Look in the project directory for the file, not the Debug subdirectory.  A somewhat plausible reason that file is there because you once ran the program yourself instead of letting the debugger start it.  And no, %programdata% is not writable by default either, %appdata% is the recommended storage location in winland.

Comment: many thanks @HansPassant , although I always followed the `programdata` wisdom as probably well described here: https://www.howtogeek.com/278562/what-is-the-programdata-folder-in-windows/ ...  This local log "thingy" is not that prominent as we primarily use our own syslog client, and excellent https://syslogwatcher.com/